# I get an error when setting a Django date field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm trying to set a date field to a constant date. My "models.py" with the date field:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.DateField()
```

In my view:

```
import datetime
from app.models import Foo

foo = Foo(bar=datetime.date('1/1/2021'))
```

The error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing a string to `date()` method. You should pass integer inside like this:

```
foo = Foo(bar=datetime.date(2020, 1, 1))
```

[Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with strptime function of datetime:

```
import datetime
from app.models import Foo

foo = Foo(bar=datetime.datetime.strptime('1/1/2021',"%d/%m/%Y").date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
import datetime

date_object = datetime.date.fromisoformat('2021-01-01')

foo = Foo(bar=date_object)
```

See here [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)